# How to add a third criteria .find

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is working at the moment. I would like to add some extra details to it which I can't seem to make work. Now when it looks for an "origin" criteria it only looks for 2 variables. I would like to make it 3. I would like to add:

> If origin = "Name" then CopyRows "B", KeyToFind, (I don't know if this should be True or False)

Then in the private sub now it only distinguishes between 2 variables and here too a third one should be added but I don't know how to do that because at the origin function it can only differentiate between "True" or "False".

What is messing this up for me is that the offsets in the private sub change with the 3rd criteria.

Is there a way to add a third criteria to this code?

```
Private aCell As Range
Dim wsImport As Worksheet
Dim wsInput As Worksheet
Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim wsSpec As Worksheet
Sub Export()
  
    Set wsImport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
    Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    Set wsSpec = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Specifications")
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
    
    Dim CriteriaA As String, CriteriaB As String, CriteriaC As String
    Dim origin As String, KeytoFind As String, strAdress As String
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim LastRowImport As Long, LastRowOutput As Long
    Dim i As Integer
         
        CriteriaA = wsInput.Range("F4").Value2
        CriteriaB = wsInput.Range("F5").Value2
        CriteriaC = wsInput.Range("F6").Value2
        
        Set rngDB = wsSpec.Range("h1", wsSpec.Range("h" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set aCell = rngDB.Find(What:=CriteriaA, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
       
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            strAdress = aCell.Address
            Do
                If aCell.Offset(, 1).Value2 = CriteriaB And _
                   aCell.Offset(, 2).Value2 = CriteriaC Then
                                                                        
                   origin = aCell.Offset(, 8).Value2
                   KeytoFind = aCell.Offset(, 9).Value2
                   
                   If origin = "Variabele" Then
                        CopyRows "C", KeytoFind, True
                   ElseIf origin = "Rekening" Then
                        CopyRows "D", KeytoFind, False
                   End If
                End If
            Set aCell = rngDB.FindNext(aCell)
            Loop While aCell.Address <> strAdress
        End If
End Sub
Private Sub CopyRows(Col As String, Searchstring As String, PartialString As Boolean)
    Dim copyFromD As Range, copyFromD1 As Range, copyFromD2 As Range, copyFromD3 As Range, copyFromD4 As Range
    Dim copyFromC As Range, copyFromC1 As Range, copyFromC2 As Range, copyFromC3 As Range, copyFromC4 As Range
    Dim copyFromS As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, LastRow As Long
     
    LastRow = wsOutput.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
    
    With wsImport
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRow = .Range(Col & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range(Col & "1:" & Col & lRow)
            If PartialString = False Then
                'Rekening
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Searchstring
                'Key
                Set copyFromD = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
                'Datum
                Set copyFromD1 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, -3)
                'Omschrijving
                Set copyFromD2 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, -2)
                'Bedrag
                Set copyFromD3 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, 1)
                'Variabele
                Set copyFromD4 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, -1)
            Else
                'Variabele
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & Searchstring & "*"
                'Key
                Set copyFromC = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
                'Datum
                Set copyFromC1 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, -2)
                'Omschrijving
                Set copyFromC2 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, -1)
                'Bedrag
                Set copyFromC3 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, 2)
                'Variabele
                Set copyFromC4 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, 0)
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With    
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you design the code you show us? If yes, don't you know what you need to code to search for? I mean, for 'True', `Find` will search for a partial string (in a larger one). For `False' it will search for the whole string. Now, you must how to set the necessary ranges. Even if, I can see that the ranges are only `Set`, but never used. I mean `copyFromD`, `copyFromC etc.

Comment: Hi Fane, thanks for your reply. It isn't a code I wrote myself, but I did edit the code. I posted an answer below to the question because I managed to make it work. I know the ranges are only set because this is just a part of the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was actually a lot easier than I thought. I just needed to add some extra if statements in the code. The below code is a working version of the changes I wanted to add. Perhaps it's of use to anyone else.

```
Option Explicit
Private aCell As Range
Dim wsImport As Worksheet
Dim wsInput As Worksheet
Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim wsSpec As Worksheet
Sub Export()
  
    Set wsImport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
    Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    Set wsSpec = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Specifications")
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
    
    Dim CriteriaA As String, CriteriaB As String, CriteriaC As String
    Dim origin As String, KeytoFind As String, strAdress As String
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim LastRowImport As Long, LastRowOutput As Long
    Dim i As Integer
         
        CriteriaA = wsInput.Range("F4").Value2
        CriteriaB = wsInput.Range("F5").Value2
        CriteriaC = wsInput.Range("F6").Value2
        
        Set rngDB = wsSpec.Range("h1", wsSpec.Range("h" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set aCell = rngDB.Find(What:=CriteriaA, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
               
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            strAdress = aCell.Address
            Do
                If aCell.Offset(, 1).Value2 = CriteriaB And _
                   aCell.Offset(, 2).Value2 = CriteriaC Then
                                                                        
                   origin = aCell.Offset(, 8).Value2
                   KeytoFind = aCell.Offset(, 9).Value2
                   
                   If origin = "Variabele" Then
                        CopyRows "C", KeytoFind, True
                   ElseIf origin = "Rekening" Then
                        CopyRows "D", KeytoFind, False
                   ElseIf origin = "Name" Then
                        CopyRows "B", KeytoFind, True
                   End If
                End If
            Set aCell = rngDB.FindNext(aCell)
            Loop While aCell.Address <> strAdress
        End If
End Sub
Private Sub CopyRows(Col As String, Searchstring As String, PartialString As Boolean)
    Dim copyFromD As Range, copyFromD1 As Range, copyFromD2 As Range, copyFromD3 As Range, copyFromD4 As Range
    Dim copyFromC As Range, copyFromC1 As Range, copyFromC2 As Range, copyFromC3 As Range, copyFromC4 As Range
    Dim copyFromB As Range, copyFromB1 As Range, copyFromB2 As Range, copyFromB3 As Range, copyFromB4 As Range
    Dim lRow As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim origin As String
     
    LastRow = wsOutput.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
    origin = aCell.Offset(, 8).Value2
      
    With wsImport
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    lRow = .Range(Col & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range(Col & "1:" & Col & lRow)
            If PartialString = False Then
                        'Rekening
                        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Searchstring
                        'Key
                        Set copyFromD = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
                        'Datum
                        Set copyFromD1 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, -3)
                        'Omschrijving
                        Set copyFromD2 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, -2)
                        'Bedrag
                        Set copyFromD3 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, 1)
                        'Variabele
                        Set copyFromD4 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, -1)
            Else
                If origin = "Variabele" Then
                        'Variabele
                        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & Searchstring & "*"
                        'Key
                        Set copyFromC = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
                        'Datum
                        Set copyFromC1 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, -2)
                        'Omschrijving
                        Set copyFromC2 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, -1)
                        'Bedrag
                        Set copyFromC3 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, 2)
                        'Variabele
                        Set copyFromC4 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, 0)
                ElseIf origin = "Name" Then
                        'Rekening
                        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & Searchstring & "*"
                        'Key
                        Set copyFromB = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
                        'Datum
                        Set copyFromB1 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, -1)
                        'Omschrijving
                        Set copyFromB2 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, 0)
                        'Bedrag
                        Set copyFromB3 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, 3)
                        'Variabele
                        Set copyFromB4 = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Offset(0, 0)
                End If
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
   
End Sub
```

Comment: The multiple If-ElseIf statements will be neater if you switch them to a `Select Case` statement.

Comment: You might want to indicate in the text of your answer exactly what new statements were added to make it easier to understand.